# Tax Currency Must Be Shown in Invoice

Tags: invoice, tax, currency, vat

My website's default currency is EUR, as well as the currency it charges and pays VAT (in Netherland).
We do sell in other currencies, especially GBP, but anyway obligated to present the charged VAT in the invoice in EUR, possibly within brackets.
Do you know about an extension that ensures the default currency appearance in the VAT line, no matter which currency the customer chose?